# When trying to save pgAdmin result to a file (TXT) the result is modified

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I launch my query into pgAdmin 4 v5's Query Tool I get this type of data representation (this is also what I would like to get in my export file).

[image]

Unfortunately this information is transformed when saving it to a .TXT file by clicking the following button and saving it as indicated in the subsequent image.

[image]

[image]

As you can see below, after double-clicking on the saved TXT document, it added '.0' and wrapped my long character by indicating 'e+29' up to a certain row.

Can you please indicate me how to remove those transformations ?

[image]

Comment: More information needed: 1) How are you saving to TXT file? 2) Where are you viewing the results? Add as update to your question. I'm going to say it on the display client end.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The requested information has been added to the question for more efficient response.

Comment: I'm using version 6.3 of pgAdmin and when I do 'Save results to file' it saves as a CSV file. When you double click on the file to open it what application is it opened in?

Answer (score 0):

All,

I found out the above problem is linked with the version of pgAdmin I was using, pgAdmin 4 v5 precisely.

After downloading pgAdmin 4 v6.4 the problem doesn't appear anymore.
I consider this thus as fixed, even if the cause of the problem remains unknown to me.

Thanks for your help.

Brieuc